# XLSXWriter: Formula with =CONCAT() Shows in Excel as "=@CONCAT()"?

Tags: excel-formula, xlsxwriter

When I do the following in XLSXWriter:

```
formula = "=CONCAT(A1, B1)"
worksheet.write_formula(1, 1, formula)
```

...I find the following in my workbook:

```
=@CONCAT(A1, B1)
```

...and the cell shows an `#NAME` error.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `CONCAT()` function is a so-called Future Function that was added in more recent versions of Excel (see the [Formulas added in Excel 2010 and later](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formulas-added-in-excel-2010-and-later) section of the XlsxWriter docs).

You need to write the formula like this:

```py
formula = "=_xlfn.CONCAT(A1, B1)"
```

However, as @teylyn points out there are many other simpler, and backward compatible ways of concatenating strings in Excel. You should use one of those instead.

Comment: This is extremely helpful also.  In the actual workbook I'm building, I'm running CONCAT on a large array of Excel cells, so CONCAT is perfect.

Comment: `=Concat(A1,B1)` is an array formula??? I don't think so. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2

Comment: @teylyn, you are correct. It isn't an array formula. I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Concat() is available on Windows or Mac with Office 2019 or Office 365 only.

Any other version of Excel will not recognize that function, hence the #Name! error.

Concat() replaces the Concatenate() function. Neither of these functions are required to concatenate text. The `&` operator often does the job much quicker, i.e. with less typing. For more sophistication, TextJoin() can be used (Office 365 / 2019 only).

The following formulas produce the same result.

```
=Concatenate(A1," - ",B1," - ",C1)
=Concat(A1," - ",B1," - ",C1)
=A1&" - "&B1&" - "&C1
=TEXTJOIN(" - ",TRUE,A1:C1)
```